# Application error when pushing to heroku - error in logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

just experimenting around with heroku and pushed my app successfully to heroku. However when I open up my web app I get a generic error message telling me to check my logs- copied below:

```
2014-01-25T20:22:32.711359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=zombie-twitter-project.herokuapp.com request_id=5c71b194-2edd-4cca- 8df2-7e867f9acd83 fwd="148.85.244.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I ran    heroku rake db migrate and get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateTweets
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:978:in `validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:876:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I have no idea how to go about solving this and would appreciate any insight.

Here is a link to my github repo https://github.com/BrianLobdell/zombietwitter

Best,
Brian

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` in the console?

Comment: Does it run locally? If you `bundle exec rails server`, that is?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! I ran    heroku run rake db:migrate as well as    rake db:migrate and am getting the error "multiple migrations have the name CreateTweets. Full error has been added to initial question.

Comment: Do you have to migrations called "CreateTweets"? To check, look at the names of the files in your `db/migrate` folder

Comment: I realized the root of the problem. Earlier i was off the master branch by mistake and pulled down from the master branch before I pushed and this may have caused some duplicates. I deleted the other migration named createtweets however, I am still getting the error message.

Comment: figured it out... needed to push to github, push to heroku, the heroku run rake db:migrate. However, now some functionalities on my website that work offline aren't working on the live heroku app. Specifically, I am unable to use the log in feature, and when I sign up and register a new account, I am unable to log in with the newly created account.